# How to remove gap between two rows?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to create 6 customized button (3 buttons in each row) using TouchableOpacity. I was able to add the 3 buttons in the first row but when try to add the other three buttons in the next row, for some reason it pushes the the first row up. I want the gap/height between each rows to be at most 10px.

and my other question is, when I try to wrap the customized card with TouchableOpacity, it ignores the width I specify on the StyleSheet.

I am new to react native. So, if this is dumb question to ask, I apologize.

Here is the code I have,

```
//Card component

import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";

function Card(props) {
  return (
    <View style={{ ...styles.CardSytle, ...props.style }}>
      {props.children}
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  CardSytle: {
    shadowColor: "black",
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
    shadowRadius: 6,
    shadowOpacity: 0.26,
    elevation: 10,
    backgroundColor: "white",
    padding: 20,
    borderRadius: 10,
    marginHorizontal: 10,
    marginVertical: 10,
  },
});
export default Card;

//MainPage

import React from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet, Dimensions } from "react-native";

import Card from "../components/Card";

const MainPageScreen = (props) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.body}>
      <View style={styles.cardContainer}>
        <Card style={styles.card} />
        <Card style={styles.card} />
        <Card style={styles.card} />
      </View> 
      <View style={styles.cardContainer}>
        <Card style={styles.card} />
        <Card style={styles.card} />
        <Card style={styles.card} />
      </View> 
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  body: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "white",
  },
  cardContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  card: {
    width: Dimensions.get("window").width / 3,
    maxWidth: "28%",
    height: 150,
    maxHeight: "28%",
  },
});

export default MainPageScreen;

//Here is screenshot of the buttons


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9z84U.png
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting a maxHeight of 28% which is setting the button height to 28% of parent and creates a blank space under the row. So you should remove it.

```
  card: {
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width / 3,
    maxWidth: '28%',
    height: 150,
  },
```

As for the touchable opacity, Rather than wrapping the view you can use it as the main wrapper and style it Like below.

```
function Card(props) {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.CardSytle, props.style]}>
      {props.children}
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}
```